# Why is there no critical section in the pipe?

Tags: pipe, shared-memory

Why is there no critical section in the pipe? For example, as in shared memory.
In pipe have general data, which in common use in joint processes, but  in the shared memory also have general data, which in common use in joint processes.

Comment: What is "the pipa"? Do you mean pipe?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Why is there no critical section in the pipE?

Comment: @user1823811 You can edit your own posts to fix spelling mistakes.

Comment: @jw013 protip: if you write `[edit]`, it will automatically turn into a link, like this: [edit]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, I think you're asking why its that if you used shared memory, you have to also use locking to ensure your writer and reader do not conflict, but you can write/read from a pipe without any locking. Of course, the extent of locking required depends on the data structure used; e.g., there are ring buffers that are mostly lock-free.

If so, the answer is fairly simple: a pipe is an abstraction. The locking for the pipe (to the extent the pipe data structures require it) is hidden in the kernel.

Comment: That's my _guessing_ of the intent of the question as well. We could add that the _critical section_ is actually in the kernel code for the `write` and `read` system calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for my english!
But I asked why is there no critical section in the pipe?
Critical section - it is a piece of code that accesses a shared resource (data structure or device) that must not be concurrently accessed by more than one thread of execution
For example,critical section is used in shared memory.

Comment: @user1823811 any critical sections are in kernel code—hidden behind the read and write syscalls—so you don't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe writes and reads below PIPE_BUF size (usually the same as a memory page size) are guaranteed to be atomic so there is no need for a userland synchronization mechanism to protect it - the kernel is already doing it.  Writes/reads larger than PIPE_BUF would require a synchronization mechanism.  In reality you don't often see large volumes of data pushed down a pipe in one swallow so you don't see mutexes and such being used very much but they are required when circumstances beyond PIPE_BUF arise.